# NN: outputting a probability density function instead of a single value

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

This might sound silly but I'm just wondering about the possibility of modifying a neural network to obtain a probability density function rather than a single value when you are trying to predict a scalar. I know that when you are trying to classify images or words you can get a probability for each class, so I'm thinking there might be a way to do something similar with a continuous value and plot it. (Similar to the posterior plot with bayesian optimisation)

Such details could be interesting when deploying a model for prediction and could provide more flexibility than a single value.

Does anyone knows a way to obtain such an output?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: model.predict_proba ?

Comment: @Paddy I'm thinking more about a continuous output like what you would get with bayesian stats.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I found a solution to this issue, though it adds a lot of overhead.

Initially I thought the keras callback could be of use but despite the fact that it provided the flexibility that I wanted i.e.: train only on test data or only a subset and not for every test. It seems that callbacks are only given summary data from the logs.

So the first step what to create a custom metric that would do the same calculation as any metric with the 2 arrays ( the true value and the predicted value) and once those calculations are done, output them to a file for later use.

Then once we found a way to gather all the data for every sample, the next step was to implement a method that could give a good measure of error. I'm currently implementing a handful of methods but the most fitting one seem to be bayesian bootstraping ( user lmc2179 has a great python implementation). I also implemented ensemble methods and gaussian process as alternatives or to use as other metrics and some other bayesian methods.

I'll try to find if there are internals in keras that are set during the training and testing phases to see if I can set a trigger for my metric. The main issue with using all the data is that you obtain a lot of unreliable data points at the start since the network is not optimized. Some data filtering could be useful to remove a good amount of those points to improve the results of the error predictors.

I'll update if I find anything interesting.